# Can I allocate memory to a specific java process (jms listener process)?

Tags: java, jms

I have to create a JMS client application with multiple `MessageListeners`, and I want to allocate specific memory to each `MessageListener` (I would create a separate process for each one). Is there a way to do this programmatically in Java?

Comment: How you're invoking your client application? I assume you do java YOUR_APPLICATION_NAME...

Comment: I don't understand.  If the `MessageListener`s are running in separate processes, then how do they *not* have their own memory, and how are they all part of the same JMS client application?

Comment: I am not very sure of the approach I would take, but the problem I am trying to solve is: I will have 1 spring application which on startup should initiate say 4 messagelisteners listening to 4 different queues. So, based on the need, I would want to distribute the memory to these listeners, so that I can make sure the queue of higher priority is not chocked.

Answer (score 1):

I have read your comments below query and after understanding about why you are trying to do, IMHO, got below suggestions from my side:

The famous performance rule is "**Measure & Don't Guess**".

So measure the performance for the peak load & also know your break point load. Once you execute performance tests, measure/find the statistics and then you will know what the application is capable of. Also, ensure that you are doing right amount of resilience (non-functional) tests.

Then finally according to the performance findings/results:

(1) Configure your JVM (one process) memory arguments properly

(2) Choose the right GC algorithm

**If you follow these rules, there is no need to go for `MessageListener` level tuning.**

Comment: Yes, I think I will have to take a step back and think in these lines. Thanks!